# How can I use arbitrary text as a function name in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is there a way in Rust to use any text as a function name? Something like:

```
fn 'This is the name of the function'  { ... }
```

I find it useful for test functions and it is is allowed by other languages.

Comment: the [`test` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/testing.html#the-test-attribute) doesn't have a way to give the test a different name

Comment: Out of curiosity, what language allows string literals as function names?

Comment: @SvenMarnach javascript member functions is at least one: `class A { 'a member function'() { } }; let a = new A; a['a member function']()`

Comment: @kmdreko Yeah, that's close, but you still can't do `function 'some string'() {}` in JavaScript, which seems closer to what the OP is asking here.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Common Lisp allows it, e.g. `(defun foo\ bar () 42)` and `(foo\ bar)` to invoke. This works by virtue of code being defined in terms of symbols, and the reader interprets escaped space as part of symbol regardless of context. Tcl is another example, having no problem with `proc "foo bar" {} { puts 42 }` and also `"foo bar"` (or `{foo bar}` which means the same) to invoke.

Comment: @SvenMarnach you can write `fun `this is a function\`() { ... }` in Kotlin. I've seen this used for tests there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way. According to the official [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html):

> An identifier is any nonempty ASCII string of the following form:
>
> Either
>
> - The first character is a letter.
> - The remaining characters are alphanumeric or `_`.
>
> Or
>
> - The first character is `_`.
> - The identifier is more than one character. `_` alone is not an identifier.
> - The remaining characters are alphanumeric or `_`.
>
> A raw identifier is like a normal identifier, but prefixed by `r#`. (Note that
> the `r#` prefix is not included as part of the actual identifier.)
> Unlike a normal identifier, a raw identifier may be any strict or reserved
> keyword except the ones listed above for `RAW_IDENTIFIER`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have spaces in function names (and this is true of most programming languages). Usual practice for function names in Rust is to replace spaces with underscores, so the following is allowed:

```
fn This_is_the_name_of_the_function  { ... }
```

although usual practice would use a lower-case `t`